# npm - ошибка cb.apply is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm

Нужно установить библиотеку `googleapis`, но `npm` выбрасывает ошибку `cb.apply is not a function`. Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2874

Answer (score 2):

Есть путь решения проблемы, который собрал много лайков на `github`'e

Вариант 1:

1. Перейдите в папку `C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming`
2. Удалите папку `npm` и
3. Если есть папка `npm-cache` запустите `npm clean cache —force`
4. Теперь всё должно работать, если нет - продолжаем
5. Переустанавливаем `Node.js` и все компоненты, которые с ним связаны

После пятого пункта всё точно должно заработать

[Источник](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2874)

Comment: Спасибо, огромное! А библиотеку у меня же не удалились? Я до 5 не выполнял.

Comment: @SCRIPT глобальные пакеты были удалены, так как они по дефолту находятся в папке npm. Есть мой ответ вам помог, можете принять его, нажав на галочку